# Create Table with default nextVal from sequence in Snowflake

Tags: postgresql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am currently trying to convert a postgres query to be compatible with Snowflake and work the same way.

```
Postgres 

CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS public.etl_jobs_delta_loading_id_seq
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
NO MINVALUE
NO MAXVALUE
CACHE 1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.etl_jobs_delta_loading
(
    id INTEGER DEFAULT nextval('public.etl_jobs_delta_loading_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
    job_name VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    loaded_until TIMESTAMP,
    etl_execution_time TIMESTAMP,
    execution_status VARCHAR(30)
);
```

I translated the sequence to Snowflake, but keep getting errors while trying to get the nextVal in snowflake.

```
Snowflake

CREATE OR REPLACE SEQUENCE etl_jobs_delta_loading_id_seq
    START = 1
    INCREMENT = 1

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.etl_jobs_delta_loading
(
    id INTEGER DEFAULT nextval('public.etl_jobs_delta_loading_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL, -- statement that needs to be converted
    job_name VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    loaded_until TIMESTAMP,
    etl_execution_time TIMESTAMP,
    execution_status VARCHAR(30)
);
```

I have tried various approaches on creating the etl_jobs_delta_loading table but no luck till now. Any ideas on how to implement this in snowflake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax to get value from sequence is `<seq_name>.NEXTVAL`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SEQUENCE PUBLIC.etl_jobs_delta_loading_id_seq
    START = 1
    INCREMENT = 1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.etl_jobs_delta_loading
(
    id INTEGER DEFAULT public.etl_jobs_delta_loading_id_seq.NEXTVAL NOT NULL, 
    job_name VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    loaded_until TIMESTAMP,
    etl_execution_time TIMESTAMP,
    execution_status VARCHAR(30)
);
```

Related: [Sequences as Expressions](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-sequences.html#sequences-as-expressions)

---

Alternatively using IDENTITY/AUTOINCREMENT property:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE public.etl_jobs_delta_loading
(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1), 
    job_name VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    loaded_until TIMESTAMP,
    etl_execution_time TIMESTAMP,
    execution_status VARCHAR(30)
);
```